# numeric literal 0 equals any content in a VARCHAR column

Tags: mysql, expression

In MySQL a VARCHAR field matches the 0 numeric literal but does not for numeric literal 1. What accounts for this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: According to the selected answer, the field of VARCHAR is cast to integer 0 which matches the search for integer 0. This is not a desirable default behavior in my opinion but better to program around it than to make database config more complicated. By the way, I discovered this via the C# API for MySQL in the method  MySqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue(parameter, 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last example MySQL will attempt to `CAST` your `VARCHAR` column into numeric value. When you are trying to convert non-numeric string to, for example, `DECIMAL` conversion will stop at first non-numeric character.  An empty string will match `0`

For example:

```
> select cast('x123' as decimal);
+-------------------------+
| cast('x123' as decimal) |
+-------------------------+
|                       0 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: 'x123' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

On the other hand, if you have leading numeric characters those will be converted to decimal:

```
> select cast('123x' as decimal);
+-------------------------+
| cast('123x' as decimal) |
+-------------------------+
|                     123 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In this case non-numeric trailing characters will be silently ignored. Conversion to INTEGER will happen in similar fashion with same results. More details can be found from the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html).